# Extract only part of string using regex with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract a part of string and replace it using regex in javascript. 
eg:

```
var string = "application == xyz AND location == abc AND packet.vlan == 10 OR ip == 1.1.1.1"
```

I need to replace

```
packet.vlan == 10
```

with

```
packet.vlan == VLAN-10
```

I have tried the following

```
var regexp = /(\=.+)/g;
string.replace(regexp, ("==" + "VLAN-10");
```

selection has to stop at next `OR/AND`. In case of eg above selection has to stop before the start of string `ip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex means "find any '=' sign followed by one or more characters."

You can have a look at https://regex101.com/ which provide visual ways to debug regex.

try `string.replace(/(packet\.vlan == )(\d+)/, "$1VLAN-$2");`

Note: "string" is a really bad name for a variable.

Comment: OP doesn't want `packet.vlan` replaced, only the value needs to be altered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to replace the string, `g` identifier in `RegExp` is used as `global` match (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match).

```js
var string = "application == xyz AND location == abc AND packet.vlan == 10 OR ip == 1.1.1.1"

var temp = new RegExp("packet.vlan == 10", "g");
console.log(string.replace(temp, "packet.vlan == VLAN-10"));
```

To replace the only first occurrence of `packet.vlan == 10` with `VLAN-10`, you can simply use `.replace()`.

```js
var string = "application == xyz AND location == abc AND packet.vlan == 10 OR ip == 1.1.1.1 AND packet.vlan = 11.1.1.1.11"
console.log(string.replace("packet.vlan == 10", "packet.vlan == VLAN-10"));
```

Comment: OP doesn't want `packet.vlan` replaced, only the value needs to be altered.

Comment: Updated answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to rewrite your regex:

```js
var regexp = /(==\s)(.+\b)/g;  //all chars from ==whitespace until next word boundery
    var s = "packet.VLAN == 10".replace(regexp, "== VLAN-$2"); //$2 to refer to the capturing group
    console.log(s);
```

However with these complex `sql` strings I would use other JavaScript to ensure more control. Take a look:

```js
var SQLString = "application == xyz AND location == abc AND packet.vlan == 10 OR ip == 1.1.1.1";


var edit = SQLString.split(/AND|OR/i); //split on and or
var andOrs = SQLString.match(/AND|OR/ig); //create an array with and an or.
edit.forEach(function(value, index, arr){
    //loop the array
    var prop = value.substr(0, value.trim().search(/\s/)+1).trim(); //trim the whitespaces.
    switch(prop){
       case "packet.vlan" :
           arr[index] = "packet.vlan == VLAN-" +value.split("==")[1].trim();
       break;
    }
    
    //add the original and or to it.
    andOrs[index] ? arr[index] = arr[index].trim() + " " + andOrs[index].trim() : null;
});

SQLString = edit.join(" "); //join the array parts with a whitespace.
console.log(SQLString);
```

On a final note. I'm curious why JavaScript is needed to rewrite SQL strings?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
const regex = /packet.vlan == (\d+)/g;
const str = `application == xyz AND location == abc AND packet.vlan == 10 OR ip == 1.1.1.1`;
const subst = `packet.vlan == VLAN-$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

See regex: https://regex101.com/r/93AfJr/1

OR

```
const str = `application == xyz AND location == abc AND packet.vlan == 10 OR ip == 1.1.1.1`;
var newstr = str.replace(/packet.vlan == 10/i, 'packet.vlan == VLAN-10');
console.log(newstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since i had to find the string which is packet.xxx and replace it with value. I had to loop through and find the string which consists packet. and replace it using regex.

NOTE: In packet.xxx, xxx can be any dynamic value.